# Dynamically Change Table names for Source and Destination in a Mule Flow to load data from SQL Server DB to Snowflake

Tags: mulesoft

I have requirement to Extract and load (E & L) data from Source SQL Server MS Dynamics to Snowflake. There are more than 200 tables in total. There is no transformation involved here and it is just one to one mapping and dump the data to Snowflake staging tables those are TRUNCATE and load.

I am new to Mule and was afraid that I have to create 200 flows for E & L. After doing bit research and with my previous experience in SSIS, was looking to create only 1 flow in mule where I can change the Source table query and Destination Table Query dynamically. After a day spent, was able to do this. Here is complete code which can help other people.

To change Source and Destination query Dynamically, I created a table called _Config and stored Source and Destination Queries for each table and Fetching them in flow and executing in batch. This approach will save lot of my time and I don't need to create 200 flows. also in future, If I have to add more tables as part of this process, I just need to add then to the Config Table.

Also I am working on to Capture the Data Load log for each Table Load and insert into a table. I need help so posted the question here: [Want to capture Data Load Log to a SQL or Snowflake table in Mule Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59870415/want-to-capture-data-load-log-to-a-sql-or-snowflake-table-in-mule-flow?noredirect=1#comment105871964_59870415)

In addition to above, would like to capture Error Log and Store into a table. [Want to capture Error log for a Mule Flow and looking for following information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59870996/want-to-capture-error-log-for-a-mule-flow-and-looking-for-following-information)

```html
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Shivendoo_Config](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [GroupId] [int] NOT NULL,
 [GroupName] [varchar](400) NOT NULL,
 [SourceTable] [varchar](400) NOT NULL,
 [SourceQuery] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
 [DestinationTable] [varchar](400) NOT NULL,
 [DestinationQuery] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
 [IsIncluded] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [IsManualRun] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [FullLoadFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [IsTruncate] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [TruncateQuery] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [DeltaLoadFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [IsDelete] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [DeleteQuery] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [DeltaColumn] [varchar](400) NULL,
 [DeltaValueFrom] [varchar](400) NULL,
 [DeltaValueTo] [varchar](400) NULL,
 [Comments] [varchar](400) NULL,
 [CreatedDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [ModifiedDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Shivendoo_Config] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsManualRun]
```

```html
USE [DB]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Shivendoo_Config] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Shivendoo_Config] ([Id], [GroupId], [GroupName], [SourceTable], [SourceQuery], [DestinationTable], [DestinationQuery], [IsIncluded], [IsManualRun], [FullLoadFlag], [IsTruncate], [TruncateQuery], [DeltaLoadFlag], [IsDelete], [DeleteQuery], [DeltaColumn], [DeltaValueFrom], [DeltaValueTo], [Comments], [CreatedDateTime], [ModifiedDateTime]) VALUES (1, 1, N'Full Load-1', N'dbo.ShivendooSource1', N'SELECT *, Getdate() AS Current_DateTime FROM [dbo].[ShivendooSource1]', N'STAGING.ShivendooDestination1', N'INSERT INTO STAGING.ShivendooDestination1 (FirstName, ETL_LoadDate) VALUES (:FirstName, :Current_DateTime)', 1, 0, 1, 1, N'TRUNCATE TABLE STAGING.ShivendooDestination1', 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'This is Full Load Group-1', CAST(N'2020-01-22T14:04:11.387' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2020-01-22T14:04:11.387' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Shivendoo_Config] ([Id], [GroupId], [GroupName], [SourceTable], [SourceQuery], [DestinationTable], [DestinationQuery], [IsIncluded], [IsManualRun], [FullLoadFlag], [IsTruncate], [TruncateQuery], [DeltaLoadFlag], [IsDelete], [DeleteQuery], [DeltaColumn], [DeltaValueFrom], [DeltaValueTo], [Comments], [CreatedDateTime], [ModifiedDateTime]) VALUES (2, 1, N'Full Load-1', N'dbo.ShivendooSource2', N'SELECT *, Getdate() AS Current_DateTime FROM [dbo].[ShivendooSource2]', N'STAGING.ShivendooDestination2', N'INSERT INTO STAGING.ShivendooDestination2 (LastName, ETL_LoadDate) VALUES (:LastName, :Current_DateTime)', 1, 0, 1, 1, N'TRUNCATE TABLE STAGING.ShivendooDestination2', 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'This is Full Load Group-1', CAST(N'2020-01-22T14:04:11.387' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2020-01-22T14:04:11.387' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Shivendoo_Config] ([Id], [GroupId], [GroupName], [SourceTable], [SourceQuery], [DestinationTable], [DestinationQuery], [IsIncluded], [IsManualRun], [FullLoadFlag], [IsTruncate], [TruncateQuery], [DeltaLoadFlag], [IsDelete], [DeleteQuery], [DeltaColumn], [DeltaValueFrom], [DeltaValueTo], [Comments], [CreatedDateTime], [ModifiedDateTime]) VALUES (3, 2, N'Delta Load-1', N'dbo.ShivendooSource3', N'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ShivendooSource3]', N'STAGING.ShivendooDestination3', N'INSERT INTO STAGING.ShivendooDestination3 (FullName, ModifiedDateTime, ETL_LoadDate) VALUES (:FullName, :ModifiedDateTime, :ETL_LoadDate)', 1, 0, 0, 0, NULL, 1, 1, N'DELETE FROM STAGING.ShivendooDestination3 WHERE ModifiedDateTime BETWEEN ''2019-12-01'' AND ''2019-12-31''', N'ModifiedDateTime', N'2019-12-01', N'2019-12-31', N'Delta Load Group-1', CAST(N'2020-01-22T14:14:03.643' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2020-01-22T14:14:03.643' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Shivendoo_Config] ([Id], [GroupId], [GroupName], [SourceTable], [SourceQuery], [DestinationTable], [DestinationQuery], [IsIncluded], [IsManualRun], [FullLoadFlag], [IsTruncate], [TruncateQuery], [DeltaLoadFlag], [IsDelete], [DeleteQuery], [DeltaColumn], [DeltaValueFrom], [DeltaValueTo], [Comments], [CreatedDateTime], [ModifiedDateTime]) VALUES (4, 2, N'Delta Load-1', N'dbo.ShivendooSource4', N'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ShivendooSource4]', N'STAGING.ShivendooDestination4', N'INSERT INTO STAGING.ShivendooDestination4 (Name, ModifiedDateTime, ETL_LoadDate) VALUES (:Name, :ModifiedDateTime, :ETL_LoadDate)', 1, 0, 0, 0, NULL, 1, 1, N'DELETE FROM STAGING.ShivendooDestination4 WHERE ModifiedDateTime BETWEEN ''2020-01-01'' AND ''2020-01-22''', N'ModifiedDateTime', N'2020-01-01', N'2020-01-22', N'Delta Load Group-1', CAST(N'2020-01-22T14:15:03.100' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2020-01-22T14:15:03.100' AS DateTime))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Shivendoo_Config] OFF
GO
```

```html
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ShivendooSource1](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [FirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [ETL_LoadDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

```html
CREATE TABLE [STAGING].[ShivendooDestination1](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [FirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [ETL_LoadDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Flow:
[image]

Code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:batch="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
 xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db"
 xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch/current/mule-batch.xsd">
 <flow name="From_SQL_Table_To_Snowflake_Table_FullLoad_Flow" doc:id="d1a52bb0-1014-4d18-8528-7077b9807c7f" >
  <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler - Runs Every 10 Seconds" doc:id="5ac8b208-57ec-4b58-aa7c-c411bde3c1ce" >
   <scheduling-strategy >
    <fixed-frequency frequency="10" timeUnit="SECONDS"/>
   </scheduling-strategy>
  </scheduler>
  <db:select doc:name="Select Flow Configuration" doc:id="cd8588b6-0458-430e-9779-3bba33f02065" config-ref="Database_Config-1" queryTimeout="10" queryTimeoutUnit="MINUTES">
   <db:sql >SELECT [Id], 
       [GroupId], 
       [GroupName], 
       [SourceTable], 
       [SourceQuery], 
       [DestinationTable], 
       [DestinationQuery], 
       [IsIncluded], 
       [IsManualRun], 
       [FullLoadFlag], 
       [IsTruncate], 
       [TruncateQuery], 
       [DeltaLoadFlag], 
       [IsDelete], 
       [DeleteQuery], 
       [DeltaColumn], 
       [DeltaValueFrom], 
       [DeltaValueTo], 
       [Comments], 
       [CreatedDateTime], 
       [ModifiedDateTime]
FROM [dbo].[Shivendoo_Config]
WHERE [GroupName] = 'Full Load-1'
      AND [IsIncluded] = 1
   AND [FullLoadFlag] = 1
   AND [IsTruncate] = 1</db:sql>
  </db:select>
  <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger to Get Size Of Payload" doc:id="60cbd4bc-f077-4854-9156-d5726561eb0e" message="Size Of Payload: #[sizeOf(payload)]" />
  <batch:job jobName="Master_Flow_To_Load_Data_From_SQL_Tables_To_Snowflake_TablesBatch_Job" doc:id="7381a2dd-d194-478a-bb22-31c244a3fedb" >
   <batch:process-records >
    <batch:step name="Batch_Step" doc:id="25105496-4d87-48f6-b86b-ec8635ff01fe" >
     <set-variable value="#[payload.SourceQuery]" doc:name="Set Variable to Get SourceQuery" doc:id="87ff6d56-663b-4783-a76c-a9c7f88857e4" variableName="VSourceQuery"/>
     <set-variable value="#[payload.DestinationQuery]" doc:name="Set Variable to Get DestinationQuery" doc:id="f335c1f3-9a2b-4544-8ad7-7ccb11a20977" variableName="VDestinationQuery"/>
     <set-variable value="#[payload.TruncateQuery]" doc:name="Set Variable to Get TruncateQuery" doc:id="9b359b5e-8280-4e26-88ee-8e7b68215782" variableName="VTruncateQuery"/>
     <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger to Get SourceQuery and DestinationQuery From Batch" doc:id="13ceec10-acc6-4308-b135-833b21c34e40" message="Source Table and DestinationQuery From Batch: #[vars.VSourceQuery] #[vars.VDestinationQuery]" />
     <db:execute-script doc:name="Execute script To Truncate Destination Table" doc:id="4fa31672-f5b6-4432-a490-128950c970f8" config-ref="Database_Config-1">
      <db:sql >#['$(vars.VTruncateQuery)'] </db:sql>
     </db:execute-script>
     <db:select doc:name="Select From Table Dynamic" doc:id="187ac9b7-9b94-4c97-b893-7113ab903104" config-ref="Database_Config-1">
    <db:sql>#['$(vars.VSourceQuery)'] </db:sql>
   
</db:select>
     <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger to Get Size Of Payload" doc:id="a7b61a28-192d-4c7c-bad2-dcf04f791b00" message="Record Counts: #[payload.successfulRecords]" />
     <db:bulk-insert doc:name="Bulk insert to Dynamic Tables" doc:id="7a7419d8-f1df-41b0-b705-7fc9a6f92fce" config-ref="Database_Config-1">
    <db:sql>#[' $(vars.VDestinationQuery)']
</db:sql>
   </db:bulk-insert>
    </batch:step>
   </batch:process-records>
  </batch:job>
 
</flow>

</mule>
```